# My JS Is Not Manipulating the HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to write code to put one image on a whole set of elements but allow a click to reveal certain images in certain elements.

So far, my JS hasn't changed any of the elements.  If someone could look at it and give me suggestions, I would be very appreciative.

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
const flipAllCards = function() {
  for (const card of cards) {
    card.innerHTML = `<img src="img/cardback.jpeg" alt="">`;
  }
};
flipAllCards();

function assignImages() {
  for (const card of cards) {
    const cardName = card.id;
    const imageName = `${cardName}.jpeg`;

    function flipCard(card) {
      card.innerHTML = `<img src="img/${imageName}" alt="">`;
      return card.innerHTML;
    }
    console.log(flipCard(card));
    card.addEventListener('click', function() {
      flipCard(card)
    });
  }
}
assignImages();
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="card" id="agentbrown"><img src="img/agentbrown.jpeg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="card" id="agentjones"><img src="img/agentjones.jpeg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="card" id="agentsmith"><img src="img/agentsmith.jpeg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="card" id="spoonboy"><img src="img/spoonboy.jpeg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="card" id="switch"><img src="img/switch.jpeg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="card" id="trinity"><img src="img/trinity.jpeg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to call `assignImages`.

Comment: Although your images don't load in the snippet, if you do an Inspect Element, you'll see that all the images *have* changed to `carcback.jpeg`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is make "card" class have a same "background-image" in CSS for all your cards while having empty divs. And then just add card.innerHTML images with corresponding ID's in JS when you need to flip a card